# What information is available to a rule in alfresco share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'd like to have a rule that prepends some numbering to files and folders within a workspace but since this is a new area for me, I'm unsure what information is available to the rule. I was going to have the rule fire a script when executed but this script will need the folder on which the action is being performed so that it can query children information before prepending the appropriate number to the file or folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of data known after a rule is triggered.

If you let the rule trigger a JavaScript then only the **space & document** variable are available.
Space is the folder on which the rule is triggered and document is the node itself which matches your condition.

The rule triggers an Action and can sends quite some information with it.
If you take a look at an [action](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Actions) you'll see there is a ParameterDefinition List which you can fill with any parameter you'd like.

In your action you can get this parameter and use it.